# Only rear cross lever on bullhorns

Tags: safety, brake-levers

I'm newbie.

I have bullhorns with two TT levers.
For safety, I'm considering installing cross lever(s).

I'd like to install only the rear-wheel cross lever since:

1. Setup will be less clumsy
2. When my hands are on the handlebar tops, I probably won't be at high speed, as when I'm on the tips of the bullhorns.

What do you think?

Comment: What do you mean by "less clumsy"? I think it would look better symmetric, and brake levers don't really get in the way of anything, except possibly lights.

Comment: There's nothing that speak against it. And since you don't plan to use the front brake in that case it will save some weight as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I would install both levers for safety.

No matter how careful you are, eventually you will get in a situation where you need to perform an emergency stop when your hands are on the tops, even if you are travelling relatively slowly. (I have experienced inattentive pedestrians stepping directly into my path only a few feet in front of me.)

In an emergency stop situation you will want to brake with both wheels, *and* the front wheel provides more braking power than the rear.

Comment: If it were a choice between the two, the front brake provides more stopping power.   However the rear brake is the backup and if the front brake has failed then the back is the only brake, so it also makes some level of sense to have this more accessible.  Definitely a case for both brake levers.